# Предоставляет ли Google Authenticator информацию сайтам?

Tags: безопасность, google-authenticator

Предоставляет ли Google Authenticator какую-либо информацию сайтам, у которых учётные записи используют Google Authenticator в качестве одной из ступеней многофакторной аутентификации?

Если да, то какую именно информацию?

Допустим есть сайт, где по правилам этого сайта нельзя иметь более 1 учётной записи 1 пользователю (человеку). Однако, кто-то имеет несколько аккаунтов, используя разные устройства или одно устройство, но разные браузеры и VPN.

Если использовать Google Authenticator (на одном мобильном устройстве) в качестве одной из ступеней многофакторной аутентификации нескольких учётных записей одного сайта - сможет ли этот сайт каким-либо образом получить информацию о том, что у одного пользователя имеется несколько учётных записей на сайте?

Или можно смело использовать Google Authenticator для аутентификации  нескольких учётных записей одного сайта?

Comment: Да это же просто реализация TOTP, то есть генерация одноразового пароля по секретному ключу и текущему времени. И ей инет не нужен, это **полностью оффлайновая** генерация. Банальное  "посчитать формулу от текущего времени". Никто никому ничего не сообщает, разве что гугл по своему обычаю предлагает забекапить у него. И Google Authenticator просто очередная высчитывалка формулы.

Comment: Да, но может ли быть такое, что при считывании ключа (QR-кода), при добавлении в Authenticator, Google Authenticator передаёт сайту какую-либо информацию? Например, о том, что в Google Authenticator уже реализуется TOTP другой учётной записи на сайте?

Comment: Что и кому он может передать. Добавление в Google Authenticator - просто добавление самого ключа (а это просто набор символов) и придуманного имени чтобы эти ключи отличать. И даже в qr коде зашито [вот  такое](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format) что направлено на устранение неоднозначности имен, но к сайтам это не имеет никакого отношения